# Xcode 8 Beta Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool Error

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, cocoa, interface-builder

I'm running Xcode 8 Beta on OS X El Capitan 10.11.6 Developer Beta 4. When loading a Storyboard in Xcode, Interface Builder shows the views, but no user interface elements. At the top, a message appears: *An internal error occured. Editing functionality may be limited.* There's also a button (*Report a Bug*), which shows me the log in Finder. As it seems, Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool crashed with status 11 (Console couldn't give me more details). Did anybody encounter this issue?

Find the log [here](https://www.pastery.net/watdnh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes i also have same issue.You can solve by following 3 way.

```
1)Made a product/clean in Xcode
2)Quit Xcode
3)clearing derived data folder fixed the issue for me
Preferences > Locations > Derived Data > click the arrow to open in Finder > trash it.
```

Comment: I updated to Xcode 8 Beta 2 and now the issue is gone.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this before, and it was a major issue, and I tried suggestions like the one above, with some success.  However, it didn't solve the problem, so I issued bug reports, Apple couldn't find the problem before I did. After a month of dealing with this issue, this is what I found as the cause (and I've seen it nowhere, after extensive searching):

"An internal error occured. Editing functionality may be limited." had to do with vertically stacked labels positioned within a view that also had proportioning constraints and height limitations.  Both the stack and the container it was in (the view) were in conflict with each other as to proportions and size.  This did not generate errors in Xcode, as constraint conflicts most often do.  When I modified the constraints for the stacked labels to where they were responsive to the container view they were constrained within, I solved the problem.